# How to write a generic class that Insert through hibernate without any dependency

Tags: java, hibernate, generics

I want to create a generic class that takes two parameters Source and Destination class and cast source object to destination object and insert it in destination table. Now I think I have to initialize a destination object and map it with source then through Hibernate Insert it and commit.
Up till now I have done following. I have just tried, not sure at all what to do and also if I am going in a right direction

```
package com.wsx.smap.json;

import java.lang.reflect.Field;
import java.util.List;

import com.wsx.pojo.Pojo;
import com.wsx.smap.model.Pipeline;

public class Sync<S,M> {
Class<S> sType;
Class<M> mType;

public Sync(Class sType, Class mType) {
    super();
    sType = sType;
    mType =mType;

}

public void insert(List<S> sObject){



    Class<S> sObj = (Class<S>) sType.getClass();
    Class<M> mObj=(Class<M>) mType.getClass();

    Field[] sFields = sObj.getDeclaredFields();
    Field[] mFields = mObj.getDeclaredFields();
    Object obj=mObj.newInstance();
    mObj.
    for (Field field : sFields) {
        field.getName();
        field.getGenericType();
    }
    for (Object obj : sObject) {

    }

}
}
```

Any Help would be highly appreciated. Thanks

Comment: Can you give concrete example of input-output? Just how do you imagine casting between incompatabile classes ?

Comment: Simply convert the class to `json` and parse in to other class. Thats the easiest way of doing it. Use GSON

Answer (score 1):

First some terminology: You write "cast", but what you actually do is copying.

It seems you attempt to do the copying dynamically using reflection. This is certainly possible, but in my experience always ends up being more complicated then anticipated, due to some special cases that need handling. Therefore I recommend the following

- check if existing libraries can do this job. [Dozer seems to be a possible fit](http://dozer.sourceforge.net/).
- Viswanath L recommends a serialization of the source to a String and deserialization of the String back into the destination Object. While this sounds to me like it should be slow, it is definitely something you should give a try.
- If you really build your own thing, take special care to have clean code, including lots of tests, because something like this is highly likely to require lots of changes. Especially this means that any special handling you need must go in separate classes, so you can register different handlers for certain source or target classes. It probably also means, that you want a clean separation of extracting data from the source and writing it to the destination.